# Can't import CSS file from node_modules with tilde paths in ParcelJS

Tags: css, sass, parceljs

I'm learning ParcelJS where I wanna import a CSS file from the `node_modules` folder. My Parcel entry point lives at `./src/index.html` which imports a SCSS stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/vendor.scss">
```

This file is located at `./src/style/vendor.scss`.

I googled it and came across [this page](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2857#issuecomment-478719089), where someone said to use the `~` followed by `/node_modules`. I also tried it without the `/node_modules` part.

```
@import '~/node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css'
```

This gives me the following error:

```
  /mnt/c/Users/Bas/Projects/website/src/style/vendor.scss:8:1: Cannot resolve dependency '~/aos/dist/aos.css' at '/mnt/c/Users/Bas/Projects/website/src/style/~/aos/dist/aos.css'
    at Resolver.resolve (/mnt/c/Users/Bas/Projects/website/node_modules/parcel-
```

I also tried to include the `node_modules` path in my `.sassrc` file.

```
{
    "includePaths": ["node_modules"]
}
```

It's weird, because when I import another SCSS file it works like a charm.

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

How can this happen and is there a way to solve it with using the tilde paths?

Answer (score 0):

```
@import '~aos/dist/aos.css'
```

use like this without / after ~

Comment: check this https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/4609